# Join Error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to join several tables, I receive the error

> The multi-part identifier "tblOptionalExtensionSplit.Policy_ID" could not be bound.

and

> Invalid column name 'Limit'.

```
SELECT tblpolicy.Policy_ID,
    tblpolicy.APRA_Code, 
    tblpolicy.APRA_Description, 
    tblpolicy.side_c, 
    tblOptionalExtensionSplit.Limit, 
    tblBurnAnalysis.*, 
    tblOptionalExtension.Optional_Extension_ID, 
    tblOptionalExtension.Optional_Extension, 
    tblOptionalExtension.Limit 

FROM tblOptionalExtension

INNER JOIN tblPolicy
    ON tblOptionalExtensionSplit.Policy_ID = tblPolicy.Policy_ID 
INNER JOIN tblBurnAnalysis
    ON tblPolicy.Policy_ID = tblBurnAnalysis.Policy_ID
INNER JOIN tblOptionalExtensionMatrix
    ON tblOptionalExtension.Optional_Extension_ID = tblOptionalExtensionMatrix.Optional_Extension_ID
INNER JOIN tblOptionalExtensionSplit
    ON tblOptionalExtensionMatrix.Optional_Extension_Matrix_ID = tblOptionalExtensionSplit.Optional_Extension_Matrix_ID

WHERE tblOptionalExtension.Optional_Extension = 'Company Securities Liability'

and Limit > 0
```